# ArcGIS Add-In Project Templates for VS 2015 Community Edition

Tags: visual-studio-2015, add-in, arcgis, esri, vs-community-edition

I am seeking to self-teach on creating new add-ins for ESRI's ArcGIS applications.  I am in the middle of watching a video on the subject, Developing Add-Ins for ArcGIS Desktop 10
http://training.esri.com/Courses/ts_DevelopAddIns/player.cfm

Especially see time index 9:13 in that video.  At that location, where they do a demo in Visual Studio, they have project templates that I don't have, especially ArcMap Add-In.  I am needing help understanding how I can get the correct add-ins, or whether something unusual is going on.

So I have downloaded and installed ArcGIS RuntimeSDK 10.2.0 for the Microsoft .NET Framework.  In Visual Studio, when I select New > Project and search for Arc, I only get a few templates such as ArcGIS Runtime 10.2.7 for .NET App (Windows 8.1).  But what I see in the video, ArcMap Add-In, is not present.  But add-ins are what I want to write.

Can someone help me with this?  Is there a different runtime that I have to install?  Do the Arc Add-Ins not work with VS 2015 Community Edition?

Comment: From this website, https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/09/08/visual-studio-2015-support-now-available-for-the-arcgis-pro-1-1-sdk-for-net/, I tried installing ArcGIS Pro SDK for .NET.  A new template has appeared, so I will try to create a project from that momentarily.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the ArcObjects SDK to see these project templates in VS. They are listed under downloads at myesri.com -> ArcGIS for Desktop -> ArcObjects SDK for the Microsoft .NET Framework.